# How to remove element(s) from std::vector without resizing it

Tags: c++, stl

> iterator erase ( iterator position );
>
> iterator erase ( iterator first,
>   iterator last );
>
> Erase elements Removes from the vector
>   container either a single element
>   (position) or a range of elements
>   ([first,last)).
>
> This effectively reduces the vector
>   size by the number of elements
>   removed, calling each element's
>   destructor before.

and:

> remove
>
> Removes all elements equaling the
>   given value value from the range,
>   defined by [first, last). Removing is
>   done by shifting the elements in the
>   range in such a way that required
>   elements are overwritten. The elements
>   between the old and the new ends of
>   the range are left intact. Iterator to
>   the new end of the range is returned.

Is there any way to remove elements from a std::vector within an iterator range(something like remove, but ALL elements from [first, last]) without resizing the vector? I need to keep it's maximum size that it reached at runtime to prevent reallocs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`resize` will never reduce the `capacity` of the vector - you can safely use `erase` for this.

Use `reserve` to make a vector preallocate space for a certain number of items. Unless you actually exceed this limit, no `insert` or `erase` or `resize` will lead to a realloc. If you exceed it, the vector will internally `reserve` more space - but it will not *reduce* the internal capacity.

Comment: I can't know the size. I want to make the vector to adjust its size at runtime.

Comment: @Felics: A vector will never reduce capacity (unless you `swap`) - The capacity you reach at runtime will not go down no matter how you erase elements. A vector's `size` and `capacity` are not the same.

Comment: @Felics: A vector only reallocs when it gets too big, or when to explicitly tell to get smaller. `size` gives you the number of actual elements in the vector, while `capacity` gives you the number of elements the vector can hold without reallocating.

Comment: @Erik I know that size and capacity are not the same but I read somewhere that erase will reduce it's capacity. If it will not reduce it's capacity I will use erase

Comment: @Space_COwbOy: I find that your comment can be misunderstood. If you call `resize()` on a vector providing a smaller size, you are *telling it to be smaller* but the vector will *not* reduce the capacity. There are no operations in a vector that allow you to reduce the capacity, the only way of achieving it is by *swapping* with an smaller copy of the vector, but I would not call that *telling the vector to get smaller*.

Comment: @Erik : Just for the sake of pedantry, it's worth noting that in C++0x, `std::vector<>::shrink_to_fit()` will also reduce capacity.

Answer (score 2):

I think perhaps you're misunderstanding the difference between the capacity of the vector and its size.

The capacity is how big the underlying array actually is. The size is the number of elements which are actually being used in that array.

When you call erase/remove, you're removing elements from the array and shifting items forward. However, the big array doesn't modify it's capacity. Only the size field of the vector is changed (likely just a size_t), as well as some elements being shifted around.

A simple example:
Here's an int vector with a capacity of 10, and a size of 4.

`| 1 | 2 | 4 | 8 | Garbage | Garbage | Garbage | Garbage | Garbage | Garbage |`

Now, say we want to remove item at index 1.

The operation would resemble something like this:

1. Destruct the item at index 1 (in this case, an integer 2)
2. Move all elements after index 1 which are valid forward however many places are necessary to ensure there's no garbage between the start of the array and the last valid item (in this case, shift everything forward 1).
3. Decrease the size field by how ever many items were removed (in this case, 1).

The final vector:
`| 1 | 4 | 8 | Garbage | Garbage | Garbage | Garbage | Garbage | Garbage | Garbage |`

There was no need to re-allocate any arrays because the capacity of the vector didn't change.

I'm not entirely sure on the semantics of the shift forward operation, there may be some calls to the copy constructor/assignment operator overloads (if any) when shifting items forward.

Comment: You say the final vector is  1 | 4 | 8 | Garbage | Garbage | ... | But the first Garbage is actually 8.

Comment: @Ogen I believe it is undefined behavior to assume that the first garbage has any value. It *might* have a value of 8 in every current implementation, but I certainly would not rely on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the `reserve` function to reserve space in the vector for the required number of items.

Have a look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/reserve/

Before you remove an item from the vector you could call reserve with the current size to keep the capacity the same.

> **Request a change in capacity**
>
> Requests that the capacity of the
>   allocated storage space for the
>   elements of the vector container be at
>   least enough to hold n elements.
>
> This informs the vector of a planned
>   increase in size, although notice that
>   the parameter n informs of a minimum,
>   so the resulting capacity may be any
>   capacity equal or larger than this.
>
> When n is greater than the current
>   capacity, a reallocation is attempted
>   during the call to this function. If
>   successful, it grants that no further
>   automatic reallocations will happen
>   because of a call to vector::insert or
>   vector::push_back until the vector
>   size surpasses at least n (this
>   preserves the validity of iterators on
>   all these future calls).
>
> A reallocation invalidates all
>   previously obtained iterators,
>   references and pointers to elements of
>   the vector.
>
> In any case, a call to this function
>   never affects the elements contained
>   in the vector, nor the vector size
>   (for that purposes, see vector::resize
>   or vector::erase, which modify the
>   vector size and content).

Comment: Yes, but when I call erase it will make an realloc.

Comment: Really? Why? I would have thought it would only realloc when it wants to reduce the capacity. If you've specified a reserved size then its not going to reduce capacity and so won't realloc.

Comment: @Felics: no it won't. You need to make the distinction between `size` (the number of elements in the container) and `capacity` (the number of elements it can contain without allocating more memory). In fact, a `vector`'s capacity never shrinks (so we need to use [tricks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111078/reduce-the-capacity-of-an-stl-vector) to make it fit the size), so your issue is inexistent.

Comment: @Luc Touraille I didn't know that the vector never adjust its capacity when using erase. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

```
iterator erase ( iterator first, iterator last );
```

This is what you want to do. The fact that the destructors of the elements are called has nothing to do with the maximum size (i.e. capacity) of the vector, which is usually not reduced. When you remove an element from a vector, the size of the vector (= number of contained elements) is reduced, but the capacity does not change in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

std::vector isn't reducing it's capacity when reducing it's size. In fact, to shrink the capacity of a vector, you need to use the swap-with-empty-vector idiom.