# Force std::vector to reallocate with less memory

Tags: c++, memory, vector

If I `push_back` a lot of elements and then `erase` them, the memory will still be reserved, right? So how can I force the vector to reallocate to a smaller size to conserve memory?

I'm not using C++11, so unfortunately I can't use `shrink_to_fit`.

The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111078/reduce-the-capacity-of-an-stl-vector) do not answer it for me. I don't understand what I'm supposed to swap and how to do it.

Comment: @Kunal: +1 Perfect dupe

Comment: @legends2k Can this question be un-duplicate-marked? I don't understand the answers of the other question. I've edited my question.

Comment: The other answers basically mean you copy your elements to another `vector` and then `swap` the contents of that temporary with your current vector. The hope is that the temporary will have a smaller `capacity` because it only ever contained `size` elements. After the swap, the temporary `vector`, now holding the old excess `capacity`, is destroyed and frees the memory.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now. So if I do that in a function, the scope should destroy the temporary `vector` when the function returns, right? So does `swap` do a reallocation?

Comment: `std::vector::swap` is able to simply swap internal pointers between the containers so there's no allocation or copying (it's very fast). In addition `std::swap` is specialized to do the correct thing when given standard library containers.

Comment: I just want to add that some of the answers in that other question use an unnamed temporary `vector` so it gets destroyed at the end of the expression. No additional function or nested scope is needed.

Comment: What's an unnamed temporary `vector` and how would I use one? I think that's what was confusing about the other answers.

Comment: When you say `std::vector<int>(v);` it constructs a copy of the vector `v` but it has no name and is then immediately destroyed. Saying `std::vector<int>(v).swap(v);` constructs the vector __and__ calls the `swap` member function to swap the new temporary with `v`. This is the one-step trick everyone used before `shrink_to_fit()` became available.

Comment: Here, have an upvote for an excellent explanation :)

Comment: Thanks, this is one of those things that look like magic the first time you see it but is actually quite simple once you understand what's happening.