# Memory deallocation in std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

I'm trying to figure out how the memory management for std::vector works when you remove elements. It is my understanding that once memory was allocated for the vector, no pop_back\erase action would reduce the capacity of the vector, and the only way to do so is using shrink_to_fit which was introduced in C++ 11. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It's up to the implementation whether actions on a `vector` reduces its `capacity()` (although it would have to be during an action that's allowed to invalidate iterators/references).  It's _also_ up to the implementation whether `shrink_to_fit` actually reduces its `capacity()` also.

Comment: The thing is that even if you assume other actions do reduce the capacity, I cannot see how this can be achieved without memory reallocation, and in the literature it specifically says that these actions do not perform reallocation.

Comment: @user181218 It's entirely plausible that the allocator supports re-sizing an existing allocation. The C function `realloc` does this, for example. It may not be profitable in all cases, of course, but if the shrink is big enough it may be. For example, the shrink may allow the allocator to free an entire page.

Comment: Any action that's allowed to invalidate iterators / references could conceivably cause reallocation.  It just happens that these typically are actions that increase capacity.  But, in theory, an `insert` at `begin()` could reallocate the vector.

Comment: If you need to force it to shrink: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111078/reduce-the-capacity-of-an-stl-vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, mostly.

There are only a few ways to reduce a `std::vector`'s capacity…

**Move Assignment**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int
main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1(10);
    std::vector<int> v2(20);
    std::cout << "v2.capacity() = " << v2.capacity() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Move assign v2 with less capacity\n";
    v2 = std::move(v1);
    std::cout << "v2.capacity() = " << v2.capacity() << '\n';
}
```

which should output:

```
v2.capacity() = 20
Move assign v2 with less capacity
v2.capacity() = 10
```

If the allocator involved is set a certain way, diminished capacity is not assured.  But in the common case as shown above, capacity will shrink.  If you really want to know about the nitty gritty details of how capacity might not shrink during move assignment, ask another question, and I can dig into that in detail.

**shrink_to_fit**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int
main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(20);
    std::cout << "v.capacity() = " << v.capacity() << '\n';
    std::cout << "erasing...\n";
    v.erase(v.begin() + v.size()/2, v.end());
    std::cout << "v.capacity() = " << v.capacity() << '\n';
    std::cout << "shrink_to_fit...\n";
    v.shrink_to_fit();
    std::cout << "v.capacity() = " << v.capacity() << '\n';
}
```

which will *probably* output:

```
v.capacity() = 20
erasing...
v.capacity() = 20
shrink_to_fit...
v.capacity() = 10
```

But it is allowed to output:

```
v.capacity() = 20
erasing...
v.capacity() = 20
shrink_to_fit...
v.capacity() = 20
```

**swap**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int
main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(20);
    std::vector<int> v2(10);
    std::cout << "v.capacity() = " << v.capacity() << '\n';
    std::cout << "swap...\n";
    swap(v, v2);
    std::cout << "v.capacity() = " << v.capacity() << '\n';
}
```

which should output:

```
v.capacity() = 20
swap...
v.capacity() = 10
```

I know of no other ways to shrink the capacity of a `vector` (besides obviously equivalent constructs such as `v.swap(v2)`).

A good rule of thumb is that the capacity of a vector never shrinks unless:

1. It transfers resources with another vector (e.g. move assignment or `swap`).
2. `shrink_to_fit` is called.

Oh, and I nearly forgot a third possibility:  any time you move *from* a `vector`, the moved-from `vector` might have a diminished capacity (or it might not).  It is unspecified, so you can't count on it.  In general moved-from values should be variables where you don't care what their current state is.  You will subsequently destruct them or assign them a new known state (assignment doesn't have to be via the assignment operator; could be `clear()` followed by `push_back()` for example).

Comment: That's exactly the summary I needed. Thank you very much.